# Mailchimp API cutting off members

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp

I am using this rails gem to access the Mailchimp API.
https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-ruby

```
mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP-API-KEY'])
```

My list has 59 members and I can confirm that from

```
newsletter_members = mailchimp.lists.members(listID)['total']
```

but when I try to access the data hash, it only returns 25 objects?

```
newsletter_members = mailchimp.lists.members(listID)['data'].size
```

Any ideas as to why?

I am basically trying to find if a email exists in my mail chimp list and this code is breaking because I am not getting all the members

```
mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP-API-KEY'])
listID = 'my-list-id'
email_array = []
newsletter_members = mailchimp.lists.members(listID)['data']
# the email array is cut short..not getting all members
newsletter_members.each do |member|
  email_array <<  member['email']
end
#returns true or false
member_exists = email_array.include?(user_email)
```

Answer (score 2):

Mailchimp's API defaults to return 25 items at a time. You can request more (though the limit is 100), or you can make multiple requests for "pages" of results.

To request 100 results:

```
mailchimp.lists.members(listID, 'subscribed', {limit: 100})
```

To request the next page of results (keep in mind the first page (results 1-25) is 0, second (26-50) is 1, etc.):

```
mailchimp.lists.members(listID, 'subscribed', {start: 1}) # Then to get 51-75 you'd start at 2
```

See the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-ruby/src/fc745199610bc00ecb42388a241c8018e20cc4a1/lib/mailchimp/api.rb?at=master#cl-945) for an overview of the available options.

You can also look at [Mailchimp's API docs](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/members.php) for the lists/members endpoint to see available options, defaults, etc.

Comment: i guess a better question is ... what is the most optimal way to check if an email already exists in a list of members?  Ideally I would like to run a simple query on the 'data' set